# Пишу telegram бота. Хочу, чтобы бот отправлял ReplyKeyboardMarkup без сообщения какого-либо.. пробовал вместо сообщения поставить "" но не получилось

Tags: python, telegram

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def weather(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.row('Fast Actions', 'View options')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"", reply_markup=markup)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Текст - обязательное поле от 1 до 4096 символов.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage